# unity rotate object on x-axis when moving mouse up / down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate a object on the x-axis when I move the mouse up or down (increase the x-rotation when moving mouse up, decrease when moving mouse down).

But I don't know how to do this.

I tried this script:

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 100.0F;
public float clampAngle = 80.0F;

float rotX = 0.0F, rotY = 0.0F;

void Update()
{
    // Mouse Look
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

    Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, 0, 0.0F);
    transform.rotation = localRotation;
}
```

But this controls also rotation on the y axis. I also have rotation on the y-axis, but they are controlled via keyboard input:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * -moveSpeed);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * -rotateSpeed, Space.World);
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed, Space.World);
```

and I want the mouse up/down only control the rotation on the x-axis.

If someone can help me, that would be great!

Comment: Do not include deltaTime in calculations with using GetAxis for mouse axes unless you care more about the speed the mouse moved rather than the distance. Mouse look generally speaking is NOT such a case!!

Answer (score 0):

*void Update()
{*

```
// Mouse Look
```

float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

rotX = mouseY * mouseSensitivity;

rotY = mouseX * mouseSensitivity;

transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotX, 0, 0.0f);

}